# Rails 3 Float or decimal for GPS coordinates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, floating-point, decimal-point

I need to store GPS coordinates in a database. I've heard that floats are less accurate than decimals. Is that true? If so, what reason is there to ever use floats?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want more accurate GPS coordinates, then yes decimals are the way to go. You can create them with a migration like:

```
create_table "models" do |t|
  t.decimal  "latitude", :precision => 15, :scale => 10, :default => 0.0
  t.decimal  "longitude", :precision => 15, :scale => 10, :default => 0.0
end
```

The reason people use floats is that they are usually precise enough for most use cases and use less space to store.

Comment: @jac Please see: `http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/208222` and why decimal doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @Anil not sure I follow. I use this in my application instead of floats for higher precision GPS coordinates and it works exactly as I expect it to.

Answer (score 30):

Since Earth equatorial circumference is around *40000 km* and longitude spans **360 degrees**, it follows that near the equator **1 degrees** is equivalent to **about 110 km**.

Thus:

- 0 digit precision: ±110 km
- 1 digit precision: ±11 km
- 2 digit precision: ±1.1 km
- 3 digit precision: ±110 m
- 4 digit precision: ±11 m
- 5 digit precision: ±1.1 m
- 6 digit precision: ±11 cm
- 7 digit precision: ±1.1 cm

---

However, the closer you move to the Poles, the smaller the lengths of the parallels becomes.
For example near *Paris*, which has a latitude of 48 degrees, 1 degree is equivalent to `cos(48) * 110 = 74 km`.

Thus:

- 0 digit precision: ±74 km
- 1 digit precision: ±7.4 km
- 2 digit precision: ±0.74 km
- 3 digit precision: ±74 m
- 4 digit precision: ±7.4 m
- 5 digit precision: ±0.74 m
- 6 digit precision: ±7.4 cm
- 7 digit precision: ±0.74 cm

So, field of type `DECIMAL(10,7)` would be enough to satisfy you rather precise.

Answer (score 2):

If you want 100% accuracy with your decimals, then multiply by 10**n(where n is your desired precision), and store as integer.

Float objects represent inexact real numbers using the native architecture's double-precision floating point representation.

See:

```
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Float.html
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in Paul's answer, it depends on your use-case.
A float provides a precision of roughly 6 decimal digits.
±11 cm is quite acceptable for, say, an address. and if you're displaying addresses it's unlikely that you are going to do any arithmetical operations that will compound rounding errors.